# How to customize and show drop downs lists in UI in Angular

Tags: html, angular, configuration, dropdown

In my project i have drop downs like region, subcontinent, country,city etc. Different drop downs are in different components like for an example, in **home page i have to show region, subcontinent, country** drop downs while in admin page i want to show **region, subcontinent, country,city drop downs**.
Dynamically data is coming to these drop downs.

How  can i do any configuration and show particular particular drop downs in particular html pages?Any ideas?

This is the structure of my drop down.And i have 4 of these separately to region ,subcontinent,country & city.

```
 <app-multi-select-drop-down-typeahead [isDisable]="isDisableFilters" [isMultiSelect]=multiSelect
             [inputPlaceholder]=placeHolderName [hasTypeAhead]=typeHead [titleName]=titleName[originalDataList]="regionList" 
[isActive]="isActiveRegion">
                                          
    </app-multi-select-drop-down-typeahead>
```

Can i pass another variable to this selector and define a **configuration class or kind of settings** tell that show this drop down in home page and show only these drop downs in admin page?

Answer (score 0):

#### Html: `index.component.html`

```html
    <form [formGroup]="myForm">
        <ng-multiselect-dropdown
            name="city"
            [placeholder]="'Select City'"
            [data]="cities"
            formControlName="city"
            [disabled]="disabled"
            [settings]="dropdownSettings"
            (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)">
        </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
   </form>
```

#### Component: `index.component.ts`

```js
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
        selector: 'index',
        templateUrl: './index.component.html'
    })
    export class IndexComponent implements OnInit {
        myForm:FormGroup;
        disabled = false;
        ShowFilter = false;
        limitSelection = false;
        cities: Array = [];
        selectedItems: Array = [];
        dropdownSettings: any = {};
        constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

        ngOnInit() {
            this.cities = [
                { item_id: 1, item_text: 'New Delhi' },
                { item_id: 2, item_text: 'Mumbai' },
                { item_id: 3, item_text: 'Bangalore' },
                { item_id: 4, item_text: 'Pune' },
                { item_id: 5, item_text: 'Chennai' },
                { item_id: 6, item_text: 'Navsari' }
            ];
            this.selectedItems = [{ item_id: 4, item_text: 'Pune' }, { item_id: 6, item_text: 'Navsari' }];
            this.dropdownSettings = {
                singleSelection: false,
                idField: 'item_id',
                textField: 'item_text',
                selectAllText: 'Select All',
                unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
                itemsShowLimit: 3,
                allowSearchFilter: this.ShowFilter
            };
            this.myForm = this.fb.group({
                city: [this.selectedItems]
            });
        }

        onItemSelect(item: any) {
            console.log('onItemSelect', item);
        }
        onSelectAll(items: any) {
            console.log('onSelectAll', items);
        }
        toogleShowFilter() {
            this.ShowFilter = !this.ShowFilter;
            this.dropdownSettings = Object.assign({}, this.dropdownSettings, { allowSearchFilter: this.ShowFilter });
        }

        handleLimitSelection() {
            if (this.limitSelection) {
                this.dropdownSettings = Object.assign({}, this.dropdownSettings, { limitSelection: 2 });
            } else {
                this.dropdownSettings = Object.assign({}, this.dropdownSettings, { limitSelection: null });
            }
        }
    }
```

For more information please check
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-multiselect-dropdown

Comment: i have  a separate  child component and in that child html file i  have above structure all the 4 drop downs therefore i need some configuration to show those drop downs pages wise

Comment: all dropdown have same configuration or different.

Comment: all drop downs are` <app-multi-select-drop-down-typeahead >` that this mentioned structure. 4  `<app-multi-select-drop-down-typeahead >` kind of selectors will be there with different values for variables.and these 4 containing html is my child component html file

Comment: like if i am showing region drop down in home page i want to hide it in admin page